# How to Create a List that holds 2 types of variable types in Scala

Tags: list, scala

Im new to scala so please go easy on me lol.

I need to create a list of where each spot holds an `Int,String`. So like `[(1,"string1"),(2,"String2")...]`

for example, Ive tried

```
val string1 = "something"
val string2 = "something"

List[Int,String] = List[(1,string1), (2,string), (3,string3),(4,string4),(5,string5)]
```

and I get the error - identifier expected but integer literal found.

How exactly would I get something like this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(1,"string1")` is a tuple containing an `Int` and a `String`, so type of list should also be a tuple - `(Int, String)`:

```
val string1 = "something"
val string2 = "something"
// ... rest of string values

val list: List[(Int,String)] = List((1,string1), (2,string2), (3,string3),(4,string4),(5,string5))
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example!